# Unable to activate test stimulator for alexa skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, alexa-slot

I have been into alexa development and recently I have encountered a never before situation. While trying to enable testing on a new skill, I am getting the following error on the **test** tab :

> There was a failure enabling your skill, please try again.

I know that this might happen if I do not complete the previous steps such skill information, interaction model, configuration etc. But the strange thing is that i have completed all of the above steps. My skill has :

- A valid skill name
- It has valid intents, slots and sample utterrances in my    interaction
  model
- I have successfully saved and built my interaction    model
- I have provided valid end-points ARN of my AWS lambda function, which has
  alexa-skill-kit enabled with the skill-id of my skill, in the configuration tab.

I don't think I have missed any of the requirement as it shows green tick(successful completion) on all mentioned steps before testing. But I can not enable the test stimualtaor in the **test** tab. It throws the above mentioned error message.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Go to the "**build**" tab in your Alexa Skill page. On the right side, you will find "**Skill Builder Checklist**". Make sure that all steps in the checklist are completed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Visit the invocation tab in Alexa Skill Kit Developer console. All Skill builder checklist have to be complete to start the test.

Don't forget to build your skill before run test.

Answer (score -3):

In EndPoint -> click Save Endpoints, if it successful then in Test, you can see Test is enabled for this skill ( in blue color).